# How to add spin control to the dialog box using win32 C?

Tags: c++, winapi

just want to know how to add an spin control ( in another name, up/down control ) in the dialog box using C program (win32 / code::block / mingw compiler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is by using a resource editor to design your dialog. Code::Blocks doesn't come with one, but [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) is one I've used.

If you are editing an .rc file by hand, you'd add a line similar to the following within the dialog definition section:

```
CONTROL         "", IDC_SPIN1, UPDOWN_CLASS, UDS_ARROWKEYS, 7, 22, 11, 14
```

If you want to add it programatically, you can do so through the [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(VS.85).aspx) API function, e.g.

```
HWND hwndUpDown = CreateWindow(UPDOWN_CLASS, NULL, 
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | UDS_ARROWKEYS,
                        7, 22, 11, 14, 
                        hwndDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

where the `hwndDlg` parameter is the HWND of your dialog window. A good place to call this is when you handle the WM_INITDIALOG message for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There are two ways to create a dialog. Programmatically, or via a dialog resource. In the first case, you call `CreateDialogIndirect`, in the second case `CreateDialog`. I assume you call `CreateDialogIndirect` since you mention "in C". In the dialog box template you use, simply add the spin control. You will need to identify it by name in DLGTEMPLATEEX.windowClass.